# How to get gradient shortcut working in Notepad++ with Emmet

Tags: css, notepad++, gradient, emmet

I have recently installed Emmet in my Notepad++. All the short codes are working fine. But when I tried to apply css short code in case of gradient, it is not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`lg(left,#fff 10%, #000)`

Keep in mind radial gradients are not supported yet if this is what you are trying to accomplish.

http://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/gradients/

Comment: I have tried with the above code of linear gradient (not radial) according to the documents of the Emmet, but that code is not working in Notepad++. That code runs well in Sublime Text 2. But I want this working in Notepad++.

Comment: It won't. Report it as an issue to Emmet's creator. After all the plugin is version 1.0 for Notepad++.

Comment: i reported to them although did not found any solution in it. I hope they will solve this in their next update.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a **bug** in Notepad++ version. I had also reported the [**issue**](https://github.com/emmetio/npp/issues/8). The suggested **workaround** is to **add CSS property abbreviation**, like so

```
bg:lg(left, #fff 50%, #000)
```